# Call onResume() or onCreate() from GCMIntentService

Tags: android

I am developing application that is using `GCMIntentService` for Push Notifications. So I want to refresh the Data of one `ListView` that is in a tab of my `TabActivity`. So is it possible to do that from the `GCMIntentService` when i receive and `GCMIntentMessage`?

For example

```
SecondTabActivity.callOnResume(); //or something like this
```

or

```
SecondTabActivity.callOnCreate(); // or something like this
```

I need to do this without using `startActivity(intent)`; cause If I do the SecondTabActivity is getting out of my `TabHost` and it's starting like new `Activity`. The function for refreshing the `ListView` is located at `onCreate(`) and `onResume()` in the SecondTabActivity so that is why I want to call them. If there is any other way beside this one please refer to it. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A good way is to use broadcast intents.

1. In your TabActivity's onCreate, use the Context.registerReceiver method to register a broadcast receiver for an intent named something like "MyGCMMessageReceived."
2. In that broadcast receiver, call the method that refreshes your list.

   ```
   this.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           // INSERT CODE TO REFRESH LIST VIEW
       }
   }, new IntentFilter("MyGCMMessageReceived"));
   ```
3. Make your GCMIntentService's onMessage method broadcast an intent named "MyGCMMessageReceived".

   ```
       Intent intent = new Intent("MyGCMMessageReceived");
       this.sendBroadcast(intent);
   ```

Comment: This seems like nice answer but I can't fully understand what are you trying to say. Can you please give me some sniped code?

Comment: I am still trying to do It, I will let you know if it works :)

Comment: Works like MAGIC! You are real "Life Saviour" :) Thanks a lot! Keep the good answers coming like this! I browsed 100 pages of google and couldn't find the answer, but here you are! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You should use [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) in Service to Activity Communications.

In your IntentService you send the new information via Local broadcast and in your TabActivity your have to register a receiver. In onReceive method you have to refresh your view.

Here you have an easy example: [LocalBroadcastManager example](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/Post/Using-LocalBroadcastManager-in-Service-to-Activity-Communications.aspx)